# Can you automatically know if a system is stable or causal based on its components?

Tags: stability, linearity, lti-system

[image]
suppose i have system with response Q(s)
and I know that the systems H and G are LTI ,BIBO stable and causal. can i automatically say that Q is causal and stable?

Comment: No you can't. Polarity is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. An example: Let H be an amplifier. Let G be a delay line. Both of them are stable and causal. But the closed loop can oscillate in numerous ways depending on what there happens to be initially. It's unstable as soon as the amp amplifies more than the delay line attenuates at a frequency where the delay line causes 180 degrees phase lag (assuming the amp causes no phase shift).

A practical example of the same idea is a screaming sound reinforcement system which screams because  the mic is too close the speaker.

Comment: thank i got it, so basically the problem is the feedback, if there was a system made out of a finite amount of subsystems that are stable without any feedback ot will be ok?

Comment: and what about causality, if i look at causality as being "physical" because it doesnt depend on future values, how can i "get" information from the future if no sub system can give me future info?

Comment: It's a well known joke to insert a delay line as negative feedback to an opamp. The transfer function will be "the future of the input, seen beforehand as far as the delay of the delay line". Unfortunately the system is unstable. Predictions are still used in control systems. Such systems (like missile guidance) assume the target obeys known physical laws like aerodynamics and Newton's mechanics and the random behaviour has a known statistics. I cannot imagine an unstable feedback free linear system made of linear stable and causal blocks.